# pygame too little or too many arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Whenever I try the following code it gives me this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/test pygame", line 14, in <module>
pygame.draw.lines(screen, red, 100,100, 150,200, 1)
TypeError: function takes at most 5 arguments (7 given)
```

No matter what I change it gives that or it tells me I have too little.

```
import pygame

red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
darkBlue = (0,0,128)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
pink = (255,200,200)
background_colour = (255,255,255)
(width, height) = (1000, 1000)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tutorial 1')
screen.fill(background_colour)
pygame.draw.lines(screen, red, 100,100, 150,200, 1)
pygame.display.flip()
running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
```

Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: well as it says pygame.draw.lines can take **up to** 5 arguments and you give it 7 - which is greater than 5. you can find the doc for the function and see for yourself how to call it : https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.lines if you wanted it to draw a line from (100,100) to (150,200) you should do something like `pygame.draw.lines(screen, red, False, [(100,100),(150,200)], 1)` or just use pygame.draw.line since its simpler

Answer (score 0):

Group arguments by using tuples as : 
[(100,100), (150,200)]

You can refer : https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs5nm/topics/pygame/drawing/